# Can we read number of running Tasks by Name or ID in TPL?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am trying to use new TPL .net library instead of threads. We have a specific case where before starting new Task we want to identify if there are already max number of tasks (lets say 10) running with our custom name/id.

Is that possible or do I need to maintain this in Tasks[] ?

Here is theoretical flow, we have 3 different kind of priority jobs. P1 being highest priority and p3 being lowest priority. Below table shows the flow of what will happen in the system.

Hope this make sense.

```
Running Threads P1 Jobs Pending P2 Jobs Pending P3 Jobs Pending Result
0               5               1               1               Start 7 tasks
7               0               1               2               Start 3 additional tasks
10              0               0               1               Wait for thread to free up
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351) class for limiting number of concurrent tasks. In a loop, these tasks should take jobs from one of three [queues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx)  in order of their priority (one queue per priority kind)

Comment: Even better, use [`QueuedTaskScheduler` from ParallelExtensionsExtras](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/09/9990424.aspx), it already includes support for priorities.